# Mutation Observer does not work

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mu6Cg/)

The script above does not work properly.
I wanted to replace DOMNodeInserted(Line19) to MutationObserver(line21), but when I used MutationObserver, it does not work.

```
// Line 19 (works well)
document.body.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {linkifyContainer(event.target);}, false);

// Line 21 (does not work)
var observer=new window.MutationObserver(function(mutations){mutations.forEach(function(mutation){linkifyContainer(mutation.addedNodes)})});observer.observe(document.body,{childList:true,subtree:true});
```

There should be something wrong in line 21, but I don't know what the problem is and what I should do.
I checked this with chrome28 and firefox23.
It's an extension of chrome, so I don't have to use "WebKitMutationObserver" or "MozMutationObserver".

Please tell me the solusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mutation observer code works fine. You are trying to pass `linkifyContainer` a `NodeList` argument (namely, `mutation.addedNodes`), but `linkifyContainer` expects to be passed a single element.

Compare the calls:

```
linkifyContainer(event.target)
```

and

```
linkifyContainer(mutation.addedNodes)
```

The second case is a `NodeList`, not a single DOM node, as indicated by the plural property name *addedNodes*.

Simply use `mutation.addedNodes[0]`, or a loop over `mutation.addedNodes`:

```
for(var i=0; i<mutation.addedNodes; ++i) {
    linkifyContainer(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  
I could make it work.  
mutation.target was the answer.

Comment: btw, instead of you loop you could write more concisely 

```[].forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
  linkifyContainer(node);
})```